# SQL - Pulling data from the same table with two different "where" statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following columns...

```
TestName - StepNumber - Data_1
```

I'm trying to write a query that can look for Data_1 results and average them for one day.  The TestNames are unique tests we're running, and StepNumbers are the individual steps inside of the test.  Normally, I would use something like

```
select Data_1 from table
where TestName in(1,2,3,4)
and StepNumber in(1)
```

to return all of the Data_1 results I need.  However, sometimes the data I need is located in different steps across the table.  Test 1 might have the required data in Step 2, Test 2 in step 10, etc...and in the end, I need an average of the Data_1 results for all of the similar StepNumber results. I'm not sure how I can capture this data in a single query.  There's a separate part of the query where I'm breaking it down by geography, and doing it individually would take a long time.

I'd be looking for something like...

```
select avg(Data_1) from table
where TestName = 1 and StepNumber = 2
and TestName = 2 and StepNumber = 10
and TestName = 3 and StepNumber = 5
```

If I can clarify, please let me know.  Thank you!

Comment: What are you using to determine what records fall within a specific day?

Comment: You need to use `ORs`, something like `(a and b) or (c and d)`

Answer (score 1):

```
select avg(Data_1)
  from table
 where (TestName = 1 and StepNumber = 2)
    or (TestName = 2 and StepNumber = 10)
    or (TestName = 3 and StepNumber = 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, you have **three** (or more) sets of data in your table:

1. TestName = 1 and StepNumber = 2    - cardinality N1
2. Testname = 2 and StepNumber = 10   - cardinality N2
3. TestName = 3 and StepNumber = 5    - cardinality N3

If you want the average for all three **separately**, you needs must select three columns. `AVG` in this case cannot help you as it would run the average on a cardinality of N4, this being the intersection of the three groups. So you have to do this by hand. I do not know how this would perform vs. three separate queries:

```
SELECT
    AVG(Data_1) AS OverallAverage,

    SUM(IF((TestName = 1 AND StepNumber = 2),  Data_1, 0))
   /SUM(IF((TestName = 1 AND StepNumber = 2),       1, 0)) AS AvgGroup1,

    SUM(IF((TestName = 2 AND StepNumber = 10), Data_1, 0))
   /SUM(IF((TestName = 2 AND StepNumber = 10),      1, 0)) AS AvgGroup2,

    SUM(IF((TestName = 3 AND StepNumber = 5),  Data_1, 0))
   /SUM(IF((TestName = 3 AND StepNumber = 5),       1, 0)) AS AvgGroup3
FROM table
   WHERE (
      ( TestName = 1 AND StepNumber = 2)
      OR
      ( TestName = 2 AND StepNumber = 10)
      OR
      ( TestName = 3 AND StepNumber = 5)
);
```

This kind of query can be assembled from components, i.e. programmatically depending on the groups.

[This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0a1d/1) is a SQLFiddle to show the results.